# Trying to figure out if there is a bug in jQuery or if it's something I'm doing

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

```
$(document).keydown(function (event)
    {
    alert(event.which);
    });
```

For the semicolon key, <kbd>;</kbd>, this gives 59 in Firefox and 186 in Chrome.  However, from the jQuery reference page for the keydown event, it says

"While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the key code. This code corresponds to a key on the keyboard, including codes for special keys such as arrows."

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `which` property is a "one stop shop" for which key was pressed, allowing you to ignore the differences between the `keyCode` and `charCode` properties.  That is the "normalization" that jQuery provides.

The difference in the value of `which` comes down to a difference between the way the various browsers supply the information - so you'll have to write code to handle the different values that come back.  There are [a few references](http://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20semicolon%20186) to this behavior online.

Comment: Okay thanks!  Seems like they should clarify the documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

A [quick Google search](http://musicofcode.blogspot.com/2009/01/semicolon-keycode.html) says you will simply have to test for both. This is a consistent inconsistency with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jQuery but I'd suggest sticking to keypress events for typing keys and only using keydown events for special keys such as arrows.

Comment: Sadly this isn't portable. See: https://twitter.com/jezenthomas/status/624174305685958656

Comment: @JezenThomas Not sure what you're trying to add there; your table doesn't discuss keydown events and agrees that keypress events work for typing keys.

Comment: The keypress event isn't always fired, depending on the key and depending on the browser. We have to use keypress, but usually in conjunction with keydown and keyup depending on the key you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entirety of the "normalization" that jQuery does:

```
if ( event.which == null ) {
    event.which = original.charCode != null ? original.charCode : original.keyCode;
}
```

Looks like it just gets `keyCode` if `charCode` doesn't exist.  And `charCode` is only used if `event.which` doesn't already exist.  It doesn't change the numbers around to make them consistent.